# Filtering in Scala

Tags: scala, datetime, apache-spark

So suppose I have the following data (only the first few rows, this data covers an entire year) -

```
(2014-08-31T00:05:00.000+01:00, John)
(2014-08-31T00:11:00.000+01:00, Sarah)
(2014-08-31T00:12:00.000+01:00, George)
(2014-08-31T00:05:00.000+01:00, John)
(2014-09-01T00:05:00.000+01:00, Sarah)
(2014-09-01T00:05:00.000+01:00, George)
(2014-09-01T00:05:00.000+01:00, Jason)
```

I would like to filter the data so that I only see what the names are for a specific date (say, 2014-09-05). I've tried doing this using the filter function in Scala but I keep receiving the following error -

```
error: value xxxx is not a member of (org.joda.time.DateTime, String)
```

Is there another way of doing this?

Comment: It's going to be a lot easier to help if you show us the code you actually used.

Answer (score 2):

The `filter` method takes a function, called a predicate, that takes as parameter an element of your (I'm assuming) `RDD`, and returns a `Boolean`.

The returned `RDD` will keep only the rows for which the predicate evaluates to `true`.

In your case, it seems that what you want is something like

```
rdd.filter{
  case (date, _) => date.withTimeAtStartOfDay() == new DateTime("2017-03-31")
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a function that takes a date, a list of datetime-name pairs, and returns a list of names for the date:

```
def getNames(d: String, l: List[(String, String)]): List[String] = {
  val date = """^([^T]*).*""".r

  val dateMap = list.map {
    case (x, y) => ( x match { case date(z) => z }, y )
  }.
  groupBy(_._1) mapValues( _.map(_._2) )

  dateMap.getOrElse(d, List[String]())
}

val list = List(
  ("2014-08-31T00:05:00.000+01:00", "John"),
  ("2014-08-31T00:11:00.000+01:00", "Sarah"),
  ("2014-08-31T00:12:00.000+01:00", "George"),
  ("2014-08-31T00:05:00.000+01:00", "John"),
  ("2014-09-01T00:05:00.000+01:00", "Sarah"),
  ("2014-09-01T00:05:00.000+01:00", "George"),
  ("2014-09-01T00:05:00.000+01:00", "Jason")
)

getNames("2014-09-01", list)
res1: List[String] = List(Sarah, George, Jason)
```

Answer (score 1):

I presume from the tag your question is in the context of Spark and not pure Scala. Given that, you could filter a dataframe on a date and get the associated name(s) like this:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
import sparkSession.implicits._

Seq(
  ("2014-08-31T00:05:00.000+01:00", "John"),
  ("2014-08-31T00:11:00.000+01:00", "Sarah")
...
)
.toDF("date", "name")
.filter(to_date('date).equalTo(Date.valueOf("2014-09-05")))
.select("name")
```

Note that the `Date` above is `java.sql.Date`.

Answer (score -1):

```
val dateTimeStringZero = "2014-08-12T00:05:00.000+01:00"
val dateTimeOne:DateTime = org.joda.time.format.ISODateTimeFormat.dateTime.withZoneUTC.parseDateTime(dateTimeStringZero)

import java.text.SimpleDateFormat
val df = new DateTime(new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd").parse("2014-08-12"))

println(dateTimeOne.getYear==df.getYear)
println(dateTimeOne.getMonthOfYear==df.getYear)
```

...